# Facebook PHP SDK Capture Like Event

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I need to record to the database if a user likes an iframe page tab using the official Facebook 'like' button at the top. I did a search here at stackoverflow and found a javascript snippet ...

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

But it doesn't fire for the official button (only like buttons added to the page)? I declare it after FB.init and before FB.Canvas resize inside the asynchronous call. Is there a way in PHP to capture this - possible on refresh? Either JS or PHP is okay (since JS can simply ajax a php file). The signed request contains whether they like the page or not but I need to capture it as it happens (or just happened).
Any help greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (targetUrl) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like', targetUrl]);
    });
};

I think you just need to setup the subscript inside the fbAsyncInit.

Comment: Thanks Colin, tried that - waited 24 hours - but still nothing in the analytics reports. All of the reading I did on Google and the net suggests that this only works for Like buttons on the iframe page and not the official like button above the page tab?

Answer (score 0):

Did it a purely PHP way in the end.

1: Get the signed request from facebook and extract the liked stats

2: Create a variable $liked and set to "yes" or "no" based on signed request value

3: Manipulate a session - use a session because the page gets refreshed when you "like" but the session remains (but the request value will have changed)

```
if(isset($_SESSION['likestatus'])){
    if($_SESSION['likestatus'] == "no" && $liked == "yes"){
        // do mysql updatestuff cause has liked page since session started  
        $_SESSION['likestatus'] = $liked;
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['likestatus'] = $liked;
    }    
}
else {
    $_SESSION['likestatus'] = $liked;    
}
```